# How to prevent a child process from inheriting the standard handles in Rust on windows?

Tags: windows, rust

According to the documentation of [Command.spawn()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn):

> By default, stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited from the parent.

I have tried explicitly nulling the handles out as described in [this open GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54760)

> ```
> Command::new("child.exe")
>         .stdin(Stdio::null())
>         .stdout(Stdio::null())
>         .stderr(Stdio::null())
>         .spawn()
> ```

But it doesn't work, the standard handles are still being inherited from the parent.*

The only option I see going forward is to use the underlying [CreateProcessW](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Threading/fn.CreateProcessW.html) function directly.
This gives me a bit of a headache though, as I will have to do the parsing and encoding of the application name and command line my self.
([this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/511364e7874dba9649a264100407e4bffe7b5425/library/std/src/sys/windows/process.rs#L248) is what that looks like in the standard library )

**Is there another way to create a child process in Rust on windows without inheriting the standard handles from the parent?**

* Which kind of makes sense seeing that this behavior is hard coded in the [spawn implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/511364e7874dba9649a264100407e4bffe7b5425/library/std/src/sys/windows/process.rs#L335)

Comment: Works for me. Doesn't inherit.

Comment: > hard coded in spawn - If you go a bit further you will see it will use the value set on command: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/77d50a8870a912af1def75760b9638db892717c5/library/std/src/sys/windows/process.rs#L304-L312

Comment: I've run into this as well it looks due to inherit being true always: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/511364e7874dba9649a264100407e4bffe7b5425/library/std/src/sys/windows/process.rs#L335 and I was able to use this workaround: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54760#issuecomment-1045940560

Comment: Check out the following ACP https://github.com/rust-lang/libs-team/issues/264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

At least I haven't found a way to do so.
The [workaround](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54760#issuecomment-1045940560) mentioned in the comments by [@jsturtevant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697126/jsturtevant) didn't work for me.

---

**Alternative**

I settled on using [`CreateProcessW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Threading/fn.CreateProcessW.html) directly as follows:

```rust
pub fn spawn_console_process(application: &str, args: Vec<&str>) -> PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    let mut cmd: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
    cmd.push(b'"' as u16);
    cmd.extend(OsString::from(application).encode_wide());
    cmd.push(b'"' as u16);

    for arg in args {
        cmd.push(' ' as u16);
        cmd.push(b'"' as u16);
        cmd.extend(OsString::from(arg).encode_wide());
        cmd.push(b'"' as u16);
    }
    cmd.push(0); // add null terminator

    let mut startupinfo = STARTUPINFOW {
        cb: mem::size_of::<STARTUPINFOW>() as u32,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    // Sadly we can't use the startupinfo to position the console window right away
    // as x and y coordinates must be u32 and we might have negative values
    let mut process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION::default();
    let command_line = PWSTR(cmd.as_mut_ptr());
    unsafe {
        CreateProcessW(
            &HSTRING::from(application),
            command_line,
            Some(ptr::null_mut()),
            Some(ptr::null_mut()),
            BOOL::from(false),
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            Some(ptr::null_mut()),
            PCWSTR::null(),
            ptr::addr_of_mut!(startupinfo),
            ptr::addr_of_mut!(process_information),
        )
        .expect("Failed to create process");
    }
    return process_information;
}
```